# Privilégios de usuários

Tags: php, html

Bom,estou com um exercício para faculdade que é a criação de um blog.Pode conter 4 usuários diferentes: Usuário(só lê post e comenta) Redator(Cria os posts e gerencia comentários) ADM(gerencia todos os posts e comentários) ADM Geral controle total do sistema (criar,editar.excluir qualquer elemento incluindo usuários e permissões)

Para criar post,alterar permissões etc, é necessário uma barra de navegação no site,minha dúvida é: Como posso fazer aparecer as opções correspondentes na barra para cada usuário?

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["new"]="limitado";
require_once('BdClass.php');
if(isset($_GET['login']) and isset($_GET['senha'])){
$objBd = new bd();
$objBd->conecta_mysql();
$param= array();
array_push($param, $_GET['login']);
array_push($param, $_GET['senha']);
$sql="SELECT nome,senha,id,tipo from usuario where nome=? and senha=? and ativo = 1;";
$result=$objBd->exec($sql,'ss',$param);
$valor=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($valor['nome'])){
    $_SESSION["nome"]=$valor['nome'];
    $_SESSION["senha"]=$valor['senha'];
    $_SESSION["id"]=$valor['id'];
    $_SESSION["tipo"]=$valor['tipo'];
    $_SESSION["ativo"] = 1;
    header("location:1.html");
}
else{
     echo "<script>alert('Se cadastre antes para logar no site');</script>";
 }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <title>INICIO</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="Pagi.php">Oh...Blooog!</a></li>
  <<li><a href="Login.php">Cadastro</a></li>
  <!--<li><a href="apagar.php">Apagar a Merda do Meu Cadastro!</a></li>-->
  <!--<li><a href="index.php">Sair Desta Bosta de Site</a></li>-->
  <!--<li><a href="bf.html">&Ocirc; Bibsfiha</a></li>-->
</ul>
<form method="GET" action="Login.php">
    <label>Nome: </label>
    <div><input type="text" name="login" value="">
    </div>
    <label>Senha: </label>
    <div><input type="password" name="senha">
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="ok">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloque o código que você já fez, e aponte qual é o problema.

Comment: Poste o que já tem ou tentou fazer para ajudarmos

Comment: Você terá de usar condicionais `IF...` para verificar o tipo de usuário, você utilizará algum banco de dados? Pode monstrar para nós em forma de código o que você já tentou, assim fica mais fácil te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isto de várias maneiras.

Vou mostrar um exemplo bem simples usando sessão do php como identificador do usuário:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-
controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle     navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<?php session_start(); if($_SESSION['usuario_admin']!=''){ ?>
      <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Postar <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Comentar</a>
  </li>
 <? }
elseif (...) // escrever  outras condições
 ?>
// escrever otras funções de acordo com cada tipo de usuário
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

espero ter ajudado, abraço!